# Objective-C: How to find the highest value in an array without sorting?

Tags: objective-c

Im working on an assignment in which I have to find the highest value in an array using a for loop, and without sorting it. I feel like what I have so far is close to being correct but not quite there. Below is an example of the code I have so far.

```
NSArray *unsortedArray = @[ @2, @44, @11, @99, @35 ];


for (int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++) {
    id number = [unsortedArray objectAtIndex:i];
    id largestNumber = 0;
    if (largestNumber < number) {
        largestNumber = number;


        NSLog(@"%@ is the largest number", largestNumber );

  return 0;
    }

}
```

Now this is only returning the first value in the area then the loop is stopping, am I assigning the wrong values to largestNumber and number? Very new to code, so I would appreciate and feedback and examples.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have a return 0 in there?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Key-Value-Coding solution, no loop

```
NSArray *unsortedArray = @[ @2, @44, @11, @99, @35 ];
NSNumber *maxNumber = [unsortedArray valueForKeyPath:@"@max.self"];
NSLog(@"%@", maxNumber); // 99
```

See this interesting article by Mattt Thompson:
[KVC Collection Operators](http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/)

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception .. this class in not key value coding compliant for the key max

Comment: @Shiva *This class*. What class?

Answer (score 1):

KVC answer is best, but if you want to do it with a loop..

```
NSArray *unsortedArray = @[ @2, @44, @11, @99, @35 ];

NSNumber *l = [unsortedArray objectAtIndex:0];
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    l = ([[unsortedArray objectAtIndex:i]integerValue] > [l integerValue] ? [unsortedArray objectAtIndex:i]:l);
}
NSLog(@"Largest = %@\n",l);
```

Also, given you have *five* objects in the array, your loop invariant must test for `i < 5`, *not* `i < 4`. That will stop at index 3, when you should stop after index 4. Finally, this compares integer values only as it stands, if you want to compare floating point or other numeric types. You should remember to specify the appropriate property. You can see them all [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/).

**Edit**: **(Downvotes for what? This answer *is* correct..)**

To clarify since you're new, an `if` statement can also be written as follows:
`a = (b > c ? (return this if true):(return this if false)`

Answer (score 0):

I am ignoring the return 0, as I am unsure about what your purpose is. But you need to declare id largestNumber outside the loop to keep tracking it

```
NSArray *unsortedArray = @[ @2, @44, @11, @99, @35 ];

NSNumber *largestNumber = @0;
for (int i = 0; i < [unsortedArray count] ; i++) {
    NSNumber *number = [unsortedArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([number isGreaterThan:largestNumber]) {
        largestNumber = number;
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@ is the largest number", largestNumber );
```

This will keep track of changes to the largestNumber array and then log the result after it's finished iterating.

There is also another approach which uses foreach approach

```
NSLog(@"%@ is the largest number", largestNumber );
NSNumber *largestNumber = @0;
for (NSNumber *number in unsortedarray) {
    if ([number isGreaterThan:largestNumber]) {
        largestNumber = number;
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@ is the largest number", largestNumber );
```

If you want me to explain foreach, just comment

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I noticed a change you made in the for loop where "i < 4" is now " i < [unsortedArray count]" Does this make it flexible to any size of array, where the previous one would only work with arrays containing 5 objects?

Comment: You can't use `<` on `NSNumber` objects.

Comment: @rmaddy this is true, but I am using it there to simply convey comparison. It can simply be accessed & compared with intValue or IntegerValue, so I didn't think to include it.

Comment: @adeslauriers89 yes, it makes it flexible so you can you pass in as many as you need.

Comment: Will do, but my goal here was to show a more generic approach compared to specific to the problem. So OP could take more away from it then just this specific problem.

Comment: @rmaddy Actually I just did a quick test and NSNumber can be compared with using < & >. So if you could remove your downvote that would appreciated

Comment: Actually you can't in general. Though it may work with certain numbers as a special case due to some implementation details. But never rely on that. It work work in many cases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99864/discussion-between-cstreel-and-rmaddy).

Comment: The comparison only works because of `NSNumber`s being created as [tagged pointers](http://objectivistc.tumblr.com/post/7872364181/tagged-pointers-and-fast-pathed-cfnumber-integers). This is an implementation detail; they are still pointers and it is still incorrect to treat them as simple value types like this. If they weren't tagged pointers, this would not work at all.

Comment: @JoshCaswell can you join nschat Discussion, I would like to talk about that in further detail.

Comment: @CStreel please correct your code, your answer is harmful for beginners in `ObjectiveC`

Comment: @Cristik no here has explained why it is harmful yet. only saying that it is wrong. I will happily change it once it's been shown to me how and why it is wrong.

Comment: `id largestNumber = 0;` is only semantically incorrect, however `if (largestNumber < number)` is the harmful one as comparing two objects with `<` compares only their memory addresses and not the actual content they are pointing to. Have you tried running your code and see how it behaves?

Comment: I agree that point id largestNumber = 0; should be updated to at least be initialised. But yes I have tested comparing two NSNumber objects using the < and it works as intended.

Comment: BOOL result1 = @3 > @4; & BOOL result2 = @3 < @4; This behaves as I expected. I haven't tested when numbers approach the upper limits but it behaves as I expect when comparing two Numbers.

Comment: I just tested with negatives and it failed, updating my answer

Comment: What's this made up `isGreaterThan:` method? There is no such method on `NSNumber`.

Comment: It's not a made a up method, I was extra sure and wrote it out, compiled and tested. It exists, just checked where it is defined and it's defined in NSObject (NSComparisonMethods)

Comment: If you're on a runtime that doesn't use tagged pointers, that code will break. If Apple changes the implementation at some point, for example. You cannot **reliably** use primitive comparison operators for object values.

Comment: I found the confusion. `isGreaterThan:` is available in OS X but not iOS.

Answer (score -1):

You've got too much inside the for loop.

You need to put the declaration of largestNumber outside the for loop. Also you might be missing a `}` since the "return 0" in the if statement will exit the entire function immediately and since its inside the for loop it exits on the first pass through.

```
id largestNumber = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++) {
    id number = [unsortedArray objectAtIndex:i];

    if (largestNumber < number) {
        largestNumber = number;
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@ is the largest number", largestNumber );
return 0;  // Not sure if you even need this
```

Comment: Good point! I was trying to keep it as close as possible to the original. Yours is probably the best answer, like the "New largest" output to help clarify what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It worked after applying your changes, could you explain why largestNumber had to be outside of the for loop?

Comment: @adeslauriers89 The `largestNumber` variable needs to hold the largest value across each loop. Due to the concept of scoping, all the variables created inside the loop are no longer accessible outside the loop or in the next iteration of the loop. So when you declare it inside the loop you are creating a new variable called `largestNumber` each time around the loop and assigning it to zero.

Comment: @adeslauriers89 This is a pretty important concept - you may want to add more NSLog statements and print out all the variables each time through the loop so you understand. You can then put the declaration inside and outside the loop and see what happens.

Comment: You can't use the `<` operator on `NSNumber` objects.

Comment: @AdamB Oh ok I see, thanks a lot I'll try that out so I can get a better understanding of how it all works.

Comment: You can't use the `<` operator on `NSNumber` objects. You are assigning `NULL` to the `largestNumber` variable, not `@0`. Even if these issues are fixed, it still wouldn't work with negative numbers since the initial value (`0`) is higher than negative numbers. Also where did `4` come from?